# Accessing wordpress directory without slash (/) shows page not found

Tags: wordpress

My website is subhafelix.com and I have installed wordpress blog at subhafelix.com/blog.

My blog works only when I type a trailing slash at the end like subhafelix.com/blog/.

Can someone please throw some light on how I can make it work without the trailing slash? (i.e) subhafelix.com/blog

Thanks

Comment: This is a forum for programming issues, but your question isn't. Please use [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)  instead or possibly [Server Fault](http://serverfault.stackexchange.com) .

Comment: check .htaccess file